# string manipulation in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

RCPT10-66631 IS A varchar value retrieved from database.

How to add 1 in it. that is i want to take next value

i.e RCPT10-66632.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string but i think that is not better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s varchar(50)
set @s = 'RCPT10-66631'
select cast(cast(right(@s, len(@s)-charindex('-', @s, 0)) as int)+1 as varchar(50))
```